# AdvancedUserInteractions alternative for AndroidDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm writing automated test cases for a mobile website, somehow the back button appears in the DOM, but is only clickable after mouseover. AndroidDriver is able to find the Element, but it's not clickable. I am not sure why, but it's working fine with the FirefoxDriver. I guess AndroidDriver can't deal with mouseover since there is no mouse ;-)

So I figured out that I use *AdvancedUserInteractions*, but that is not working:

*underlying driver does not implement advanced user interactions yet*

It works fine with the FirefoxDriver, so are there any alternative for AndroidDriver?

```
WebElement BackButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'left menu Stuff__landscapeOnly')]"));

actions.moveToElement(Zurueck).build().perform(); 
//Back.click();
jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", Zurueck,"click", "0,0");
```

How to deal with mouseover using AndroidDriver?

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby, I used..

```
include Selenium::WebDriver::DriverExtensions::HasTouchScreen

@driver.touch.single_tap(element).perform
```